# Kubernetes Ingress redirect to a directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

using ingress example in kubernetes. I've been trying to browse but couldn't understand how to rewrite ingress to take a file which needs from the website with the ingress object in kubernetes from a folder

Here is the example:

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
      name: tomcat-ingress
      namespace: default 
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: rewrite.bar.com
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: tomcat-deployment-service
              servicePort: 8080
            path: /tomcat/?(.*)
          - backend:
              serviceName: nginx-deployment-service
              servicePort: 80
            path: /nginx/?(.*)
```

AND here how is done in our local nginx server:

```
  location ~* /company/logo/[0-9]*/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
                root /opt/comapny/docs-branch/;
                rewrite /company/logo/([0-9]*)/(.*) /$1/$2 break;
```

I'm trying to figure out how when accessing this endpoint to redirect to a folder so it can take its file when needed. Also shall it try to access them from the nginx controller pod or the pod that has the service with the ingress

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to add [custom config snippets to an Ingress via annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~* /company/logo/[0-9]*/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
          rewrite /company/logo/([0-9]*)/(.*) /$1/$2 break;
      }
```

You can easily break things here, so to view the eventual config file in the ingress-controller pod:

```
kubectl get pods
kubectl exec mingress-nginx-ingress-controller-8f57f66d-mm9j7 cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | less
```

Comment: Let's say it will try to use /opt/comapny/docs-branch/; Will it look for that folder in the ingress controller pod?

Comment: Yeah, there's no content on the controller. The `root` is not useful here, just whatever you need the redirect to be so it sends the client to the correct URL for your service.

Comment: It says to me when trying to save the ingress yaml: # * : Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": [yaml: line 8: mapping values are not allowed in this context, invalid character 'a' looking for beginning of value]

Comment: Sounds like the quote block `|` might not be correct. Look for the lines starting with `a`

Comment: Also I'm not trying to imply that is the correct redirect config, I just copied your config into the snippet. Once you can get the yaml right, check the config file to see if that looks sane.

Comment: Thanks, mate for the help. Here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/nrr4f9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193753/discussion-between-danny-and-matt).